# malloc'ing for field inside struct

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have, roughly speaking, a function prototype like this:

```
init_superstruct(const char *name, Superstruct **super, int num_substructs) {...
```

where superstruct looks like

```
typedef struct superstruct {
    char *name, 
    Substruct **substructs, 
    int num_substructs;
} Superstruct
```

The function is supposed to

1) allocate memory for (and initialize) super, by...

2) ...assigning the name field of super enough memory to hold the name argument, and...

3) ...assigning the substructs field enough memory to hold an array pointers to Substructs (of size num_substructs).

**My question**: will the following code accomplish these goals?

```
*super = malloc(sizeof(*super));
*super->name = malloc(sizeof(strlen(name) + 1)));
*super->substructs = calloc(num_substructs, sizeof(Substruct));
```

---

This is literally my first foray into dynamic memory allocation. Any advice you have would be helpful for me!

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(strlen(name) + 1)));`<<- strlen() yields a size_t, so you alloc `sizeof(size_t) +1` here ... AND: youneed a `';'` after `} Superstruct`

Comment: @wildplasser I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Is size_t not what I want here?

Comment: I rolled back your edits. They may solve the errors, but they render the answer(s) useless.

Comment: @Chris: read about [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). That could be useful in your case: you could exchange the order of `substructs` & `num_substructs`then end your `struct` with `Substruct *substructs[];`

Comment: BTW, there is a typo in the question; `Substruct **substructs` should be followed by a semi-colon `;`not by a comma `,`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok, noted

Comment: "allocate memory for (and initialize) `super`" --> I doubt that is the correct goal.  I'd expect "allocate memory for (and initialize) `*super`".

Comment: @chux you're correct that we're not initializing `super` - really we're initializing `**super`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would not recommend using flexible array member for any new code (except possibly specialized high performance scenarios)... they were only added to the standard to allow any existing code using the struct-hack to be made compliant.  They are more problematic to use than normal structs.

Comment: @M.M. That is your opinion, and I strongly disagree with it. Flexible array members are a very useful feature of C99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
*super = malloc(sizeof(*super));
```

You want `sizeof(**super)`. `*super` is a pointer, with type `Superstruct *`, so this won't allocate enough memory.

Really, you should probably allocate the structure normally, then assign it to the pointer separately. This will make your code much easier to write:

```
Superstruct *r = malloc(sizeof *r);
r->name = …
*super = r;
```

---

Second:

```
*super->name = malloc(sizeof(strlen(name) + 1)));
```

This is wrong. `sizeof(strlen(name) + 1)` is `sizeof(int)` (or perhaps `sizeof(size_t)`; either way it's not what you want) -- `strlen()` won't even be called! Remove the `sizeof()` from this expression to make it correct.

---

Third: to allocate a single array of `Substruct` objects, define the structure member as `Substruct *substructs`, and allocate it using the exact code you've got right now. You don't need a double pointer unless you want an array of *pointers* to the structures, which is more complicated than you need.

If you really think you do need an array of pointers here (you probably don't), you need to allocate the array using `sizeof(Substruct *)` as the `size` argument to `calloc()`, not `sizeof(Substruct)`.

Comment: I do want an array of pointers to the structures, because that's the prototype I'm supposed to work with. And I understand your first point (about **super) but can you comment on the rest of what I wrote?

Comment: I've added some notes about the `name` field which I omitted earlier.

Comment: @Chris: why dont you *return* the pointer to the allocated(array of) struct, instead of passing it by "reference"?

Comment: Aw nuts. Ok, I should have caught that 2nd one.

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff. I think this answered all of my questions for now :)

Comment: @chux Thanks -- I changed that variable's name at the last moment and missed that reference.